# Prepostions followed by that-clauses

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis, subordinate-clauses

It’s commonly said that prepositions take declarative clauses without *that*. However:

> 1. The apartment is nice **except that** the rent is too high.

> 2. You can't always **count on it that** someone will help.

It seems that Prepositions "except" and "on" are both followed by that-clauses(serving as objects).

In the second example, why should "it" be used and placed between "on" and " that"?

Comment: '... count on it' means '... rely on that'. And ' ... count on it that ...' means ' ... rely on the fact that ...'. The second 'it' is merely a grammatical device used to postpose the event that you can count on. The structures are fixed expressions.

Comment: I saw " rely on it that..." , but found no sentences with " rely on that...". It seems some prepositions can't  be directly followed by that-clauses.

Comment: The _that_ clause are not objects. In 1. the content clause is a complement of (and licensed by) the preposition "except". In 2. it's licensed by the whole expression "count on it".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on false assertions and it includes no other examples or research to give the question required foundation and clarity.

Comment: @Benjamin Harman, Though your demonstration of the second example was not entirely convincing, it explained something reasonable. It is sad that even the linguists in our country didn't give a convincing demonstration.

Comment: @Benjamin Harman, As you said,  " except" is not a preposition but a conjunction ( assume "except that" is combination) in the first example; what is the specific name of this clause?  I don't think it is a coordinate clause or an adverbial clause.

Comment: @Benjamin Harman, I posted this question because I was told by our linguists that both that-clauses in my post served as objects of the relevant prepositions. I doubted about their definitions but I wasn't able to explain why.

Comment: @user421993 "Except" is best classified as a preposition, not a 'conjunction'. Prepositions can license **declarative content clauses** (_that_ clauses), but in your second example it is not a preposition that licenses the content clause but the whole phrase "count on it".

Comment: @BillJ, Your comment is convincing.  Frankly, Upvote or downvote means nothing to me; I don't care.  What I expect is a solution or an answer.

Comment: @BillJ +1 Yes, but it’s rare and noteworthy for a preposition to take an expanded declarative (as opposed to one without *that*). This question needs an answer explaining about the extraposition in the second example. Shall we get this reopened? Two more reopen votes needed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes - but the *it* has no special place, I don't think in the idiom. You can count on a person, a thing, an idea etc etc. The *it* is required here just because the preposition *on* will not take declarative content clauses as a complement  (and as you say the dummy *it* allows for an extraposed object). Note that if w used a gerund-participle there would be no problem: *count on someone helping.*

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I agree.  IMO, assume prepositions can't be immediately followed by " that -clause"; the dummy "it" is not a real object and its only function is to take the place of "that clause"(the real object) grammatically. If so, it seems more convincing than explanation of ellipsis.

Answer (score 2):

This is what comes from relying on *`What Is Commonly Said`* for grammatical rules.
The correct rule is

1. Some prepositions can take tensed clauses with *that*.
2. Some prepositions can take tensed clauses without *that*.
3. Some prepositions can't take tensed clauses.

As to which prepositions belong in which class, that has to be learned individually;
the first two classes overlap because *that* is normally optional with tensed clauses.

Comment: I’ m curious about these rules, especially the first two classes. Can you give me any clues about "some prepositions", for instance,  if you don't mind listing some of these prepositions for reference?

Answer (score 1):

I don't entirely agree with the OP's proposition:

> prepositions take declarative clauses without *that*

For example, you can't omit *it* without rendering 2 ungrammatical:

> 2'. **You can't always count on* (*that*) *someone will help.*

Note that 2' is ungrammatical with or without *that*.

Thus, some prepositions such as *on* cannot take declarative clauses with or without *that*.

Having said that, I believe examples of a preposition taking a *that*-clause as complement are few and far between. Most of these rare examples are not even legitimate examples, if you will.

In 1, for example, the preposition *except* taking a *that*-clause as complement can be better explained by ellipsis, as shown below, than by considering it a legitimate example of a preposition taking a *that*-clause as complement.

> 1. *The apartment is nice except* (*for the fact*) *that the rent is too high.*

Comment: Can you explain another example shown in DICTIONARY.COM, " In that you will be busy for the next few weeks, let's go over your paper now." ?   Can " In that" be explained by ellipsis?

Comment: Ellipsis usually refers to omitted words that can be recovered from contextual clues. That doesn't seem to be the case here. We could just as easily say that there is ellipsis in a _because_ construction using the logic above - _They were angry __because (of the fact that) I was late.___

Comment: @DW256 Good point on the definition of ellipsis! I'm not really well-versed in exact linguistic terms, so why don't you tell me what I should call that kind of omission. // The possible omission of "of the fact that" after "because" is neither here nor there in that I'm specifically discussing examples of a preposition taking a _that_-clause as complement.

Comment: @user421993 I for one wouldn't use "In that" in the DICTIONARY.COM example, because I would be using "Since" or "Because" instead. Although DICTIONARY.COM says that "in that" is synonymous with "because", I don't think they are generally interchangeable. "In that" in its idiomatic use is a short form of "in the sense that".

Comment: @JK2 I'm not convinced that there is anything omitted there, just like there's nothing omitted in the above example I provided if the part in parentheses were not there in the first place. Simply because it is possible to insert a few words into an expression (and maintain the same sense) does not mean that they are required in some way and present in an invisible form whenever the expression appears without them.

Comment: @DW256 I don't think there's only one way to explain things. There just are different ways of explaining the same linguistic phenomenon. Either you make examples like "except that" and "in that" exceptions to the general rule that prepositions generally don't take _that_-clauses as complement, or you invoke the concept of omission, or you don't even endorse the general rule but simply claim that it's on a case-by-case basis. Take your pick, and I think you picked the first one. That's your call. All I'm saying is, the second one sounds better to me than the others.

Comment: 'In that you will be busy for the next few weeks, let's go over your paper now.' I'd rewrite this, but if one is forced to suggest a retrievable unellipted sentence:  'In the situation that you find yourself in – a situation that means you will be busy for the next few weeks – let's go over your paper now.'